# Can sets be transformed into a similar form.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was solving a problem on using the venn diagram to see if the set is a subset of another, and I concluded that it was. The book presented that theorem that $(P\cup Q)\setminus Q  \subset P$, and I was wondering if I could transform the sets into this form. This was the problem that was to be done with the venn diagram $(A\cup B)\setminus C$ and $A\cup (B\setminus C)$, and have concluded from the diagram that the former is a subset of the latter. If let Z be some set, is it possible to transform from $ (A\cup B)\setminus C$ to this form: $$[(A\cup (B\setminus C))\cup Z] \setminus Z$$ 
so that I can conclude that $(A\cup B)\setminus C \subset A\cup (B\setminus C)$ by using the theorem $(P\cup Q)\setminus Q  \subset P$? I have been trying to do the transformation but I failed so either it can't be done or I am just that bad at this topic.

Comment: Finding $Z$ is more easier using *Venn diagram*. You know already that $(A\cup B)\setminus C \subseteq A\cup(B\setminus C)$. Can you guess, using Venn diagram (if necessary) , what is *"left out"*?

Comment: @Krish I have not thought of that.  It kinda makes sense.  Much amazed. I'll try it.